# Change existing migration or generate new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

My project has 100+ migration, mostly cause things were introduced, removed and then introduced back again. ie I have a lot migration which look useless to me.
Additionally, rails started adding deprecation warning when I run migration:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `#timestamps` was called without specifying an
>   option for `null`. In Rails 5, this behavior will change to `null:
>   false`. You should manually specify `null: true` to prevent the
>   behavior of your existing migrations from changing.

I think to get around above warning, I will need to edit migration files. Would it be bad idea to write fresh new migration (on basis of my current schema), since my migration history is already messed up?
You might say that migration keeps record what has happened in history but don't I already have git for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem for Rails programmers who actively develop an app for some length of time.  The practice my group follows is that when we are convinced we're at a point that we'll never rollback to migration #X, we'll rollback the recent migrations we intent to keep, copy the generated `db/schema.rb` as our new "initial migration" and then just keep the newer ones after the initial.  This will spare you from those deprecation warnings and will lighten up your codebase and repository as well.

Hope this helps.